# Passing params on promise.done?

Tags: jquery

I have a promise, and when it's done I wish to run my getContentAll method:

```
p_numContentTotal.done(getContentAll);
```

I also wish to pass in a param to that method (the context of the script as I wish to access global vars in the method):

```
 p_numContentTotal.done(getContentAll(ctx));
```

But by adding this, the method gets run straight away, how can I get round this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in anonymous function:

```
p_numContentTotal.done(function () { getContentAll(ctx) });
```

Or explicitly push `ctx` as a context of a function and use `this` to access `ctx` variable inside it:

```
function getContentAll() {
   console.log(this); //will print your ctx variable
}
p_numContentTotal.done(getContentAll.bind(ctx));
```

Comment: Or wrap both the function and the context in the same closure, ensuring that the context will be valid when you access it. Note the differences between reference and value access to the context object. Your question asks for reference access, but the two answers posted above provide value passing.

Comment: p.s. if ctx is never reassigned, they will work identically for you.

Comment: If IE8 (or less) is in the range of supported browsers you should use [`$.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) instead of [`.bind()`](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Function.prototype.bind) to set the context of a function

Answer (score 1):

Usually you'll want your entire script enclosed anyway, to control the namespace. Once you've done so, accomplishing your goal of accessing the current context of your script is already done. This 'javascript closure' is what provides the "anonymous function" capability Artyom mentioned.

How you wrap it is up to you. Simply, your entire script may be an object, a function, a block, or a callback from document ready. Ultimately, this is what allows the magic to happen in other methods anyway.

```
function main() {
    var ctx = 'current state';
    $("button").click(showContext);
    function showContext() {
        alert(ctx);
    }
}
$(main);
```

example here: http://jsfiddle.net/s6VDE/1/

note that this preserves reference access (which may or may not be what you want), as demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/s6VDE/5/